1 John 2:15 In this context, what is the theological significance and inference of "the Father's love is not in you"?
1 John 2:15 NET

Do not love the world or the things in the world. If anyone loves the world, the love of the Father is not in him.


This is less complicated than it appears - the answer revolves around the meaning of the Greek accusative, dative and genitive cases. Essentially, 1 John 2:15 presents two objects of love that are mutually exclusive - a person either has love for the world or for the Father, but never both.  Let me be more specific.
Here is my (overly literal) translation of 1 John 2:15 set out to show the grammatical structure:

A: Do not love [imperative] the world nor the [things] in the world;
B: If anyone should love [subjunctive] the world, [he] does not [have] the love of/for the Father in him.

Note the structure - part "A" is a command not to love the world.  Part "B" is the consequence of disobeying that command - the consequence is that the love of the world excludes any love we have for the Father.  Jesus said almost exactly the same thing in Matt 6:24 -

No one can serve two masters: Either he will hate the one and love the
other, or he will be devoted to the one and despise the other. You
cannot serve both God and money.

That is why it is so important not to love the world - it excludes our ability to love the Father.  Ellicott expresses it thus:

If any man love the world — Esteem, desire, or pursue it, or any thing in it, inordinately, so as to place his happiness in the
enjoyment of it; the love of the Father is not in him — There
being a real inconsistency between the love of the world and the love
of God; between being carnally minded, esteeming, desiring, and
pursuing immoderately visible and temporal things, which is death, and
being spiritually minded, having our thoughts and affections set on
invisible and heavenly things, which is life and peace,

APPENDIX - Genitive Case

In Koiné Greek, the genitive case ending has potential to express the
widest range of meanings of all the various case endings. The genitive
case ending can express possession, description, kinship, apposition,
separation, the subject of a verbal idea, the object of a verbal idea,
and others. [from https://ugg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/case_genitive.html]

The final sentence contains the phrase: ἡ ἀγάπη τοῦ Πατρὸς = "the love of the Father".  This genitive construction could mean any oof the following:

the love the Father has for others; this is "attributive" or perhaps, "subjective"
the love we have for the Father; this is the "objective"
the love belonging to the Father; this is "possessive"

Some of these meanings can be immediately eliminated from John's intended meaning:

the attributive and subjective meaning cannot be intended because we know that God loves all people as per John 3:16 and others.
the possessive meaning cannot be intended because then the love is the Father's and so by definition cannot belong to us.

This leaves the objective meaning - the love we have for the Father is that which is excluded by our love of the world.  Hence my translation above.

+1 but it raises another question for me. (coming soon)

never mind... it's already been asked and answered.

The genitive could also mean the love from the Father. Anyone who loves the world does not have the love from the Father in him. The idea is the same but makes clear the love is from the Father.

@RevelationLad - that is true as documented above - see first dot point.

The first epistle of John presents as a treatise on love, at the heart of which is the love of the Father, a love that is characterized by the desire to redeem that which it loves. It is not love in the abstract, but one that is manifested through concrete action.
1 John 4:9-10 ESV

9 In this the love of God was made manifest among us, that
God sent his only Son into the world, so that we might live through
him. 10 In this is love, not that we have loved God but
that he loved us and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our sins.

The Father showed his love by sending his only Son. The Son made known his love by laying down his life for us. We in turn abide in the love of the Father and the Son by loving one another, manifesting that love through acts of charity and mercy.
1 John 3:16-17

16 By this we know love, that he laid down his life for us,
and we ought to lay down our lives for the brothers. 17 But
if anyone has the world’s goods and sees his brother in need, yet
closes his heart against him, how does God’s love abide in him?

While it may not be its only purpose, the primary function of the genitive case in “the love of the Father” is understood to be ablative, indicating source (Case Genitive: Separation/Source (or Ablative)). The love of the Father is the love that has its source in the Father. The implication being that those who are the children of God are not defined by the love they have for the Father, but by the fact that they have received and shared of the Father’s love.
1 John 3:1

See what kind of love the Father has given to us, that we should be
called children of God; and so we are.

1 John 4:19

We love because he first loved us.

